# Tagging notifications prevent future notifications. Whats the workaround?

Tags: reactjs, service, push-notification, service-worker, workbox

Im trying to use tags to prevent too many notifications on the user screen.
I try the tag suggested here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/tag

And now it doesn't show anything. Or it shows once and never again. How can we best show fewer notifications but not block them completely?

```
self.addEventListener('push', event => {
  let body, destination;
  if (event.data) {
    const payloadObj = JSON.parse(event.data.text());
    body = payloadObj.body;
    destination = payloadObj.destination || '/';
  } else {
    body = 'New notification';
    destination = '/';
  }

  const options = {
    tag:"tag",
    body,
    icon: `${process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_URL}/icon-512.png`,
    vibrate: [96, 69, 100],
    data: {
      dateOfArrival: Date.now(),
      primaryKey: 1,
      destination,
    },
```

Comment: It sounds like you might be incorrectly reusing tags. What code are you using to send the notifications and generate the tag?

Comment: @Smitop added code